# Мультиязычные комментарии в Java-коде

Tags: java, комментарии

Хочу выложить свой первый проект на GitHub для Android. Проект как на рус. так и на англ. языке. Код прокомментирован на русском языке, хочу также его прокомментировать еще и на английском как минимум. Подскажите, как это лучше сделать? Как это делают, может есть какие-то статьи почитать? Погуглил - толком ничего не нашел. Не в скобках же писать на английском языке коммент после русского...

Comment: > Не в скобках же писать на английском
> языке коммент после русского...


ну а как по другому?

Comment: @discord Ваша правка коренным образом меняет вопрос, делая невозможным дать на него конкретный ответ. В любом языке это невозможно, но в JavaDoc вполне решаемо.

Comment: Убрал любой-язык

Comment: @ReinRaus В тексте вопроса "код прокомментирован", что я воспринимаю как обычные комментарии, поясняющие код, а не исключительно документирующие комментарии, предназначенные для генерации референсной справки. Самый заплюсованный ответ тоже не специализирован ни на документирующих комментариях, ни на конкретеом языке. То же касается и обсуждения. Ваш специализированный на джавадоке ответ, может быть, и полезный, но оторван от реальности. Детальнее ниже.

Answer (score 9):

Если проект мультиязычный, то он комментируется ТОЛЬКО на английском языке. Всё.

Comment: Да и во всех остальных случаях так же желательно использовать английский язык для комментирования и документации, ибо редко когда возможно заранее утверждать, что к проекту не будут привлекаться носители другого языка.

Comment: Не знаю, я в code.google.com комментировал как-то так:

    // Блок управления очередью и свободными блоками
    typedef struct {
      Q_BLOCK *head, *tail, 
        *flist,     // список свободных блоков, полученных malloc()
    ....
    } DATA_QUEUE;
    /*
    // The control unit queue and free blocks
    typedef struct {
      Q_BLOCK * head, * tail,
        * flist,   // ​​list of free blocks received malloc ()
     ....
    } DATA_QUEUE;
    */

и вроде никто не ругался.

Comment: Зачем так категорично? Комментировать можно на любом языке, только навряд ли такой код заинтересует кого-то кроме носителей родного языка комментатора.

Answer (score 1):

```
\**
 * <div class="en">English</div>
 * <div class="ru">Русский</div>
 */
 class Foo
```

Comment: Это явно не для [любого языка] подходит.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev посмотрите, когда изменен вопрос и когда дан ответ. К сожалению, правка discord полностью меняет смысл вопроса. В итоге из точного ответа как это сделать в JavaDoc получился вопрос на который нельзя дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: А, точняк. Это он, конечно, зря сделал.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev По поводу моего исправления см. комментарий к ответу. Что касается этого решения, то я не представляю, как его претворить в жизнь. Во-первых, оно касается только документирующих комментариев. Во-вторых, оно не масштабируется на большое количество языков, потому что даже при одном языке шапки методов уже могут превышать все разумные границы.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev В-третьих, что наиболее важно, эти комментарии будет невозможно поддерживать. Требование знать один язык для понимания и обновления комментариев превращается в требование знать два. В вопросе говорится про опен-сорс. Эти комментарии будут гарантированно протухать, а потому будут более вредными, чем их полное отсутствие. В целом, костыль для жабодока прикольный, конечно, но абсолютно бесполезный.